# Parsing API Response in EJS

Tags: json, ejs

I'm receiving the following API response:

```
{
    "address": "0xd7",
    "ETH": {
        "balance": 0,
        "price": {
            "rate": 1675.5593679319497, ...
        }
    },
    "countTxs": 0,
    "tokens": [{
        "tokenInfo": {
            "address": "0xa",
            "name": "USD Coin",
            "decimals": "6",
            "symbol": "USDC",       
            "price": {
                "rate": 1.00051504943475,
                "diff": -0.15,
            },
            "publicTags": ["Stablecoins"]
        },
        "balance": 37500000000,
        "totalIn": 0,
        "totalOut": 0
    }, {
        "tokenInfo": {...
    }]
}
```

I'm sending it from my server to frontend with `res.render('ethereum', {user: req.user, eth: response})`

I'm trying to extract the info from each token. I've tried a couple of different methods below. Everything below returns a blank value.

```
<% for (let token in eth.tokens) { %>
            <tr class="table-row">
              <td><%= JSON.stringify(token.tokenInfo.name) %> </td>
              <td><%= token.balance %> </td>
              <td><%= token.balance %></td>
              <td>$<%= token.rate %> </td>
              <td> </td>
           
              <td>$0</td>
          
              <td class="1d"></td>
              <td class="7d hide"></td>

            </tr>
          <%  } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I hadn't set `json:true` in the API call.